# Change template or HTML indentation in NetBeans

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans6.7

How to change HTML template in NetBeans 6.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Using file templates in NetBeans 6.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212044125/https://blogs.oracle.com/marek/entry/using_code_templates_in_netbeans) :

Go to "Tools"->"Templates", and select the HTML-template. By selecting a template and clicking on "Open in Editor" button you can view or edit the template in NetBeans Editor window.

[image: List of templates]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](https://blogs.oracle.com/marek/resource/screenshots/nb-codetemplate-dialog.png))</sub>

Comment: in netbeans 6.7 HTML-template isn't exist

Comment: Then you should be able to create your own, and then choose "Save as..." -> "Template" and put it the folder with the other templates.

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans 6.7 HTML template should be in "Tools > Templates", "Web" section. If it isn't there, maybe you've downloaded "Java SE only" version? Or any other of the downloads that don't contain "Java Web and EE"? You cand download either "Java" or "All" version from [here](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html). If you are going create html, or maybe some other files from that "Web" category, then you are better off getting full version right now. It will save you a lot of trouble later.

Or you can just add that template by creating "Html.html" file with the following contents (that is the default template from NetBeans):

```
<#assign licenseFirst = "<!--">
<#assign licensePrefix = "">
<#assign licenseLast = "-->">
<#include "../Licenses/license-${project.license}.txt">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=${encoding}">
  </head>
  <body>
    TODO write content
  </body>
</html>
```

Then going to "Tools > Templates" window, clicking "Add" button and selecting that file.

And if you want to change indentation for those kind of files, go to "Tools > Options", "Editor" section, "Formatting" tab, select in "Language : All Languages" and change the "Number of spaces per indent" to your desired value. If "Expand tabs to spaces" option is selected, then "Tab size" field determines how many spaces will be inserted when you hit tab.